# Shiny interactive plots: ternary plots third axis variable?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, interactive, ternary

Based on the information in
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selecting-rows-of-data.html
I'm making my first experiences with interactive plots.

With a normal plot (on a cartesian coordinate system), all is great.
When it comes to a ternary plot, it's more tricky. A ternary plot has three variables and function nearPoints() has only two parameters to identify location on a plot: xvar and yvar.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
    library(ggtern)
library(shiny)
## data ####
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,1,5), y=c(45,29,10), z=c(10,45,94),
                 ss = c(58,75,109))
################
runApp(## UI ####
   list(
     ui = (basicPage(
       headerPanel("interactive tests"),
       mainPanel(
         plotOutput("f1", click = "plot_click1"),
         verbatimTextOutput("info1"),
         plotOutput("f2", click = "plot_click2"),
         verbatimTextOutput("info2")
       )
     )),

     ## server ####
     server = function(input, output) {
       output$f1 <- renderPlot({
         plot(dd$x,dd$y)
       })

       output$f2 <- renderPlot({
         figura <- ggtern(data = dd,
                          aes(x = x,y = y,z = z)) +
           geom_point()
         print(figura)
       })

       output$info1 <- renderPrint({
         nearPoints(dd, input$plot_click1, xvar = "x", yvar = "y")
       })

       output$info2 <- renderPrint({
         nearPoints(dd, input$plot_click2, xvar = "x", yvar = "y")
       })
     }
   )
)
```

The first plot is a simple scatterplot, in which clicking an observation returns the appropriate line in the dataframe.

The second plot is a ternary plot, and in this case it does not work.

If someone has a solution or can point me in the right direction, it'd be great.

Thanks,
António

Comment: you mean a 3D plot? google 3D plots in shiny.

Comment: While trying to solve the problem by adapting the source code of nearPoints(), I haven't been able to find a way to calculate distances between points in a "ternary space". Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Not a 3D plot, a ternary plot (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot)